# SQL Server : DateTime column, time 00:00:00.000

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2.

I have a table which has column of `DateTime` datatype. I wish to be able to input a value using SQL Server Management Studio, edit view. If I type the date it accepts it. However it will put the time as:

```
2016-10-12 00:00:00.000
```

Is there anything I can change so that it will include the time whenever I type the date?

Excluding the obvious of actually typing in the time...

Comment: you want to input a time without inputting it ? I dont understand your question

Comment: current_timestamp?

Comment: do you mean the date AND time now?  in which case GETDATE() gives that, or do you mean enter any date and add the current time to it?  You don't need to key in today's date, SQL can find that

Comment: Yes so I want to come along and type 
    12/10/2016 and what gets added is 2016-10-12 10:24:35.015, i.e. the current time.

Comment: yes, but why do you want to key in today's date, but not the current time?  Would you key in 2016-10-01?  Would that have a time?  Have you considered GETDATE() without keying in either date or time?

Answer (score 0):

To put the current time onto any given date, but retaining that date

```
declare @D as datetime = '20160506';
SELECT              DATEADD(
                                MILLISECOND, 
                                DATEDIFF(millisecond,
                                DATEADD(day,    
                                        DATEDIFF(day, 
                                                 0,
                                                 GETDATE()
                                                 )
                                        ,0)
                                ,GETDATE())
                                ,DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,0,@d),0))
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name , sorry I had caps lock lock on, it wasn't a statement - man, people here complain that SQL keywords are in lower case - sorry anyway